# Non-zero wedge product of linearly independent vectors in $\Lambda^2 V$.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, exterior-algebra

Do we assume as part of axioms, that **Wedge Product** of two linearly independent vectors in $V$ will be non-zero?

If not, can we show just using axioms of **Wedge Product** that wedge product of two linearly independent vectors of $V$ is non-zero? I know, if we can write $\Lambda^2 V$ as isomorphic to quotient space $\dfrac{F(V\times V)}{S(V\times V)}$, with their usual meaning, then we can easily show it, but I was thinking of proving it directly from bi-linearity and self-annihilation property of **Wedge Product** on $\Lambda^2 V$.

Comment: I don't understand, what definition of exterior product are you using?

Comment: @BennyZack  Their bi-linearity and the fact that $u\wedge u =0$

Comment: No, because the wedge product's being identically $0$ would be consistent with the axioms you're assuming. You can't even begin by showing that $e_1\wedge e_2\ne 0$, when $e_1,e_2$ is a basis for a two-dimensional $V$. Indeed, you have not given us a definition of the wedge product.

Comment: It's not assumed as part of the axioms, and it does not follow from bilinearity and antisymmetry.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Then can't I just define wedge product to be all zero and it wouldn't violate bi-linearity and anti-symmetry property of wedge product ?

Comment: The exterior square is defined to 1) satisfy bilinearity and antisymmetry and 2) be *universal* with respect to this property. You can write down something that satisfies 1), and by universality it will be a quotient of the exterior square, such as the zero quotient. But the exterior square itself is special.